# How to use Vue with multiple pages?

Tags: vue.js

I want to use Vue with multiple pages but I guess they have some changes in vue.config.js. Now it is renamed to vite.config.js and it has some changes in it.

I tried to write the following codes but when I try to reach http://localhost:5173/demo.html it opens the index.html which is not in the public directory. I am confused here.

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { resolve } from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        demo: resolve(__dirname, 'public/demo.html'),
      },
    },
  },
})
```

What I am doing wrong here? Also how I am supposed to set .js and .vue files?

Comment: It's not _"renamed"_, you're now using a completely different tool (Vite, rather than Vue CLI).

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. demo.html isn't expected to correspond to /demo url. You can configure a webserver in prod to do this.

Comment: Sorry, in my case the my web server automatically converts /somepage.html to /somepage. I'll update my question.

Comment: *Vue.js is an open-source model–view–viewmodel front end JavaScript library for building user interfaces and **single-page** applications.* I think you don't know what vue.js is..

Comment: @Wimanicesir, Vue was created to manipulate DOM. Virtual URLs are just addition. I am using it just for 2 way data binding because it is the best framework for 2 way data binding.

Comment: I would not know how you would create your pages then. A new Vue instance for every page? Just to name something, state management is simply impossible between those two. Yes, Vue has a useful toolbox to make development easy. But IMO it doesn't matter if you have to do crazy adjustments to make it work on every page in your application.

Comment: @Wimanicesir, I don't do adjustments when moving from page to page. It is not a single page application. I use the following configuration https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages but it looks like Vue CLI is no longer maintained so I guess it will be better for me to move to Vite, unfortunately its multi page support is not documented well or may be it doesn't work.